# Converting CLLocationCoordinates2D into an NSValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation

I'm simply trying to convert `CLLocationCoordinates` into an `NSValue` to be used in an array brought back later in my app. Here is my code:

```
  NSUInteger count = [self.locations count];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        coordinates[i] = [(CLLocation *)self.locations[i] coordinate];
        NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinates[i]];
        [_locationsArray addObject:locationValue];
        NSLog(@"location = %@", _locationsArray);
    }
```

However the `NSLog` displays that the array is filled with (Null) values. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong here, an someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check that count is not 0.

Comment: When you convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to NSValue using NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate];
It forces you to include ***MapKit.framework*** to your project, if you want to avoid it, use solution proposed by [Andrey Chernukha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/994107/andrey-chernukha) NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&coordinates objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see any need in `coordinates`array. And you probably didn't initialised it.
Try:

```
_locationsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (CLLocation *location in self.locations) {
    NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate: location.coordinate];
    [_locationsArray addObject:locationValue];
    NSLog(@"location = %@", _locationsArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can convert the CLLocationCoordinates2D into an NSValue by doing like below but have you check the coordinate contains any value or not once.

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&coordinates[i] objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you didn't initialize your array. That's why it's nil when you log it.

```
_locationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```